# Windows Essential Business Server Installation Issue

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have recently started a migration from Windows Small Business Server 2003 to Windows Essential Business Server 2008.

We are taking the route of joining EBS to the current domain and then decommisioning the old DC.  This seemed to be the simplest way to complete the migration.

I have run the preperation and planning wizards with no errors and everything seemed to be progressing smoothly.

Whilst running the Progress of Environment Check, one of the checks is SYSVOL and NETLOGON health check, which brings back the following error:-

The installation wizard failed to connect to the NETLOGON shared folder on domain controller SERVER.network.local. This is because another user or process is holding open a connection which is causing a credential conflict.

To continue the installation, wait for all connections to close and then click check again. If the problem persists, contact Microsoft support for assistence.

At first I though it was because everyone was logged on so I waited until everyone had gone home and tried again.  Same error.  I then tried closing down every other server and network device that we had accept the old domain controller and the new management server same thing again.

We currently have the following servers and network devices on our network.

Terminal Server
Terminal Server Backup
Application Server
SQL Server
Netgear NAS Drive

All current SBS functions are controlled by one single server.

The strange thing is that I can see the old DC from the new server and I can navigate to the NETLOGON shared folder without issue.  I can ping each machine from the other.

I have googled for hours trying to rectify this but to no avail :(

If anyone has any ideas they will be much appreciated.

Cheers

Jim

Comment: You know that EBS has been discontinued, right? http://www.microsoft.com/ebs/en/us/default.aspx

Comment: Was about to comment the same as joeqwerty - putting a lot of effort into migrating to a discontinued product isnt the best thing to do. I believe MS is offering the equalent stand-alone products for all EBS customers.

Answer (score 0):

Discontinued product concerns aside, the message you're seeing sounds like a manifestation of the classic error 1219:

> Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

The message you're receiving isn't, obviously, the same as above, but it just *feels* like that kind of error to me.

The background on the error I'm describing is fairly simple: One user logon session cannot make multiple Microsoft "File and Print Sharing" connections to the same remote server using different credentials. You can trigger this behavior by using the "NET USE" command with a "/USER:domain\other-valid-user" argument to map a drive to a server that you already have another drive letter mapped to.

When you get to the point where the EBS installer is going to perform this "check", open a command prompt and run "NET USE * /d /y" on the server computer. This will disconnect any open "File and Print Sharing" sessions for that user. My gut says this will make your installer happy.

Comment: Hi Evan, thanks for the reply.  I am aware that EBS has been discontinued but the explanation as to why we are still performing the migration would probably take up most of this page :)

I have tried what you suggested but to no avail I'm afraid.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else has this issue, it was resolved by a simple restart of the Workstation service on the management server.